# Elasticsearch Cluster fails on shutting down one node

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I setup an Elasticsearch Cluster with 3 nodes. Here are the values i changed in elasticsearch.yml

Node Earth:

```
cluster.name: FederationOfPlanets
node.rack: Sol
node.name: Earth
node.master: true
node.data: false
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation: false
```

Node Enterprise:

```
cluster.name: FederationOfPlanets
node.rack: Sol
node.name: Enterprise
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
index.number_of_shards: 2
index.number_of_replicas: 2
index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation: false
```

Node Defiant:

```
cluster.name: FederationOfPlanets
node.rack: Bajor
node.name: Defiant
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
index.number_of_shards: 2
index.number_of_replicas: 2
index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation: false
```

The nodes Enterprise and Defient are running with logstash agents to get logs from the system and put it into the elasticsearch instance. Earth is running with a logstash web instance to show the logs in a webinterface. Everything works well until i shutdown the Defiant node. If I shutdown the Enterprise node, everything works well.

How can i avoid the the cluster failure if one node stops working?

Comment: Can I know the order you start the elasticsearch node?

Comment: Does it matter? At first "Earth" is started, after that the two spaceships